# PHP ini_set override php.ini

Tags: php

In php.ini, I have display_errors set to off, as on most of the pages on my site I don't want errors to show up.

However, I'm writing a new thing, and I want errors on. So at the top of my script, I put

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

But errors didn't display, I just got HTTP Error 500.

So I turned it on in php.ini, and they did display.

So is there a way I can make errors display only in places I want it to, but in general, don't display?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Only way is turning on `display_errors` in `php.ini` and using `error_reporting(0);` in place to turn off all error reporting and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to turn on them

Comment: Okay, I was worried as much. Thanks though.